# Find event type that triggered hook in Jenkinsfile

Tags: github, jenkins, webhooks

I have a GitHub webhook triggering a Jenkins pipeline job. I've set several events that triggers the webhook (like push, pull requests, ...).

Once my Jenkinsfile triggered, I want to run different commands according to the type of event that triggered the hook, but I can't find any variable giving me this event type. Is there a way to find it ?

I checked the `env` variables available in Jenkins but found nothing like it. I've also seen 'hacks' checking if the variable `CHANGE_ID` exists but it seems pretty ugly and does not cover all cases.

Comment: I have the same problem (but for bitbucket), did you find a solution?

Comment: @Bert No, still no idea (and I don't work on this project anymore). Good luck with that

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed configure your Jenkins pipeline to handle different event types triggered by your GitHub webhook in a more elegant way. Instead of using "if-else" statements or relying on specific environment variables like CHANGE_ID, you can utilize the webhook payload information to determine the event type. Here's how you can achieve this:

- GitHub Webhook Configuration:
  In your GitHub webhook configuration, ensure that you include the necessary event type information in the payload. GitHub provides a X-GitHub-Event header in the webhook payload, which specifies the type of event that triggered the webhook. For example, it can have values like "push," "pull_request," "issues," etc.

[Configure Header Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aW5b7.png)

[Use the Header to match specific events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSQXj.png)

Note: We can even match more than one events using these regex [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

- Jenkins Pipeline Configuration:
  In your Jenkins pipeline script (Jenkinsfile), you can access the X-GitHub-Event header from the webhook payload. This can be done as follows:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Process Webhook Event') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def githubEvent = httpRequest(
                        url: "<webhook_payload_url>",
                        acceptType: 'APPLICATION_JSON'
                    ).headers['X-GitHub-Event'][0]

                    if (githubEvent == 'push') {
                        // Handle push event
                    } else if (githubEvent == 'pull_request') {
                        // Handle pull request event
                    } else if (githubEvent == 'issues') {
                        // Handle issues event
                    } else {
                        // Handle other event types or add more conditions as needed
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this script, we use the httpRequest step to fetch the webhook payload and extract the X-GitHub-Event header, which indicates the type of event. You can then use conditional statements to execute specific commands or steps based on the event type.

By following this approach, your Jenkins pipeline will be able to dynamically respond to different GitHub webhook events without relying on "if-else" conditions or hardcoded environment variables, making your solution more flexible and maintainable.